# Flow type: use extended class from function returning parent class

Tags: javascript, flowtype

How can I get flow to interpret the return value from `document.getElementById` as `HTMLInputElement`, not the more general `HTMLElement`?

Example:

```
let input = document.getElementById('myinput');
console.log(input.value);


script.js:28
 28:   console.log(input.value);
                         ^^^^^ property `value`. Property not found in
 28:   console.log(input.value);
                   ^^^^^ HTMLElement
```

From https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/master/lib/dom.js

```
declare class Document extends Node {
  …
  getElementById(elementId: string): HTMLElement;
  …
}
```

However, `getElementById` may return a subclass (in this case `HTMLInputElement`)

```
declare class HTMLInputElement extends HTMLElement {
  …
  value: string;
  …
}
```

I'd like to be able to access the `value` property of the input element without flow raising an error.

Comment: Can you better explain your question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that Flow compiler doesn't know what type of HTMLElement `input` variable is going to be in advance, it throws error.

Typically this is what people are suggested to do in such cases:

```
var input = document.getElementById('myinput');

if (input instanceof HTMLInputElement) {
    console.log(input.value);
}
```

Read about this technic in [dynamic type tests](https://flowtype.org/docs/dynamic-type-tests.html#a-instanceof-b) section of documentation.